# Parse float and button click

Tags: javascript, html

Having issues using a parsefloat to calculate user entered values. I've looked at my code again and again but can't determine where the error is occuring. When I click the button nothing is displaying as expected.

I have reviewed the code and the naming/id attributes of the variables.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title> Lab 4 Grade Calculator </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Grade Calculation</h2>
  <p>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value=""><br><br> Homework average: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" value=""><br><br> Lab Average: <input type="text" id="labBox" value=""><br><br> Midterm Average: <input type="text" id="midtermBox"
      value=""><br><br> Final Exam score: <input type="text" id="examBox" value=""><br><br>
  </p>
  <br>
  <!-- Start input button -->
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Course Grade" onclick="homework=parseFloat(document.getElementById('homeworkBox').value);
    labs=parseFloat(document.getElementById('labsBox').value);
    
    midterm=parseFloat(document.getElementById('midtermBox').value);

    finalexam=parseFloat(document.getElementById('examBox').value);
    

    overall_Average = homework*0.25 + Labs*0.20 + midterm*0.25 + finalExam*0.30;
    

    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello '+ document.getElementById('nameBox').value+ ', your overall course average grade is: ' + overall_Average;">

  <!-- Close input button   -->
  <hr>
  <br><br>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result is to calculate the users input values and display them on screen.

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('labsBox').value')

Comment: aka `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I fix it? I’m new to HTML

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues that need to be resolved:

1. Javascript is case sensitive, this means that when you declare a variable with all lowercase letters (eg: `labs`) you need to reference it using all lower case letters (ie: `Labs` is not the same as `labs`). You need to fix this within your code.
2. You need to get the exact `id` that you're specifying in your HTML in your JS for your code to work:

   ```
   document.getElementById('labsBox').value
   ```

   The above should be `labBox`, not `labsBox`, as your `id` is `labBox`.
3. Don't write all your javascript in the `onclick` method callback, write your javascript in `<script>` tags or in a separate file which you can then call a function to run your code. This way, you can keep your mark-up (the page structure "code") separate from your logic.
4. When you're not writing HTML to your page, it's better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

See example below:

```js
function calculateGrade() {
  var homework = parseFloat(document.getElementById('homeworkBox').value);
  var labs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('labBox').value);
  var midterm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('midtermBox').value);
  var finalexam = parseFloat(document.getElementById('examBox').value);
  var overall_Average = homework * 0.25 + labs * 0.20 + midterm * 0.25 + finalexam * 0.30;

  document.getElementById('outputDiv').textContent = 'Hello ' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + ', your overall course average grade is: ' + overall_Average;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Lab 4 Grade Calculator </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Grade Calculation</h2>
  <p>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value=""><br><br> Homework average: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" value=""><br><br> Lab Average: <input type="text" id="labBox" value=""><br><br> Midterm Average: <input type="text" id="midtermBox"
      value=""><br><br> Final Exam score: <input type="text" id="examBox" value=""><br><br>
  </p>
  <br>
  <!-- Start input button -->
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Course Grade" onclick="calculateGrade()">

  <!-- Close input button   -->
  <hr>
  <br><br>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

so many wrong with your variable java declaration has a **case-sensitve**

you need to check it before you use
[image]